# Error: Resolving configuration 'ios32Api' directly is not allowed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

I am trying to make a universal framework for iOS in KMP.
Here is my module build.gradle file

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.FatFrameworkTask

buildscript {
    ext.serialization_version = "0.20.0"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/jetbrains/kotlin-native-dependencies" }
    }
}


repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://kotlin.bintray.com/kotlinx" }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin-multiplatform'
apply plugin: 'kotlinx-serialization'

def serialization_version = "0.20.0"

kotlin{
    targets {
        fromPreset(presets.jvm, 'android')
        iosArm32("ios32")
        iosArm64("ios64")
        iosX64("simulator")

        configure([ios32, ios64, simulator]) {
            binaries.framework('Shared')
        }


    }
    //we have 3 different sourceSets for common, android and iOS.
    //each sourceSet can have their own set of dependencies and configurations
    sourceSets {
        commonMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common'
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-common:$serialization_version"
        }

        androidMain.dependencies {
            api 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib'
            implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime:$serialization_version"
        }


        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version")
            }
        }

        ios32.dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version")
        }
        ios64.dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version")
        }
        simulator.dependencies {
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-runtime-native:$serialization_version")
        }


    }

    task fatFramework(type: FatFrameworkTask) {
        // the fat framework must have the same base name as the initial frameworks
        baseName = "Shared"

        final File frameworkDir = new File(buildDir, "xcode-frameworks")
        destinationDir = frameworkDir

        // specify the frameworks to be merged
        from(
                targets.ios32.binaries.getFramework('Shared', 'RELEASE'),
                targets.ios64.binaries.getFramework('Shared', 'RELEASE'),
                targets.simulator.binaries.getFramework('Shared', 'RELEASE')
        )

        doLast {
            new File(frameworkDir, 'gradlew').with {
                text = "#!/bin/bash\nexport 'JAVA_HOME=${System.getProperty("java.home")}'\ncd '${rootProject.rootDir}'\n./gradlew \$@\n"
                setExecutable(true)
            }
        }
    }


}
configurations {

    compileClasspath
}
tasks.build.dependsOn fatFramework
```

When I try to build my Module it gives me this error

```
Execution failed for task ':Shared:linkSharedReleaseFrameworkIos32'.
> Resolving configuration 'ios32Api' directly is not allowed
```

Am I missing something in my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce the error as the question features only part of the project. So, while modifying it to make things work as a separate project rather than a module, I accidentally lost the original problem. But here are my thoughts on the possible cause.
This snippet seems to be missing the difference between source sets and targets. I mean, as there are three named targets `ios32`, `ios64`, `simulator`, the kotlin-multiplatform plugin creates six default source sets: `ios32Main`, `ios64Main`, `simulatorMain`, `ios32Test`, `ios64Test`, `simulatorTest`. But in this code, I see new source sets named `ios32` etc. being created instead of setting defaults' dependencies. This can be a problem, as there are no explicit connections between those source sets and declared targets.